# Is it is good practice to use internal localhost server for wkwebview by ionic team?

Tags: ionic-framework, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

**Official ionic doc 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#cors**

> CORS
>
> Unfortunately there’s no API to disable this, so you’ll need to ensure
>   any remote API that your app use, implement CORS correctly: CORS MDN
>   Docs
>
> Origin: http://localhost:8080 CORS checklist:
>
> Whitelist Origin: http://localhost:8080 Whitelist Methods Whitelist
>   Header CORS preflight request (OPTION)

**I don't think it as a good practice by ionic team** . Suppose if i have a back-end server where i allow 'localhost:8080' for ionic .

Then any person can make a script to hit continually to my server by hiting it from his local  'localhost:8080' server  , which can make my back-end stack .

What you think the approach to be ?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not to protect your backend from requests.

CORS can protect client (like a browser or Cordova app webview) from accessing and working with content from a backend, that doesn't think it is a good idea to do that.

If a bad actor wants to make requests to your server, they will just use a method that does not handle or respect CORS headers (like e.g. Ionic Native's Native HTTP wrapper).